# Erasing extent of one layer using another layer using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, clip, erase

I have two layer files which mark the extent of some vegetation types. The base layer includes some areas which does not need to be included. The second layer is solely comprised of unnecessary area coverage.

I need to remove this unnecessary area. I was hoping to subtract the unnecessary area layer from the base layer but am unsure how to do this. I don't have an advanced license so I cannot use the erase tool.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: An Erase is easily accomplished with a Basic level license by using the Union workaround described in the duplicate.